# Add Custom Record Type Sublist in NetSuite Advanced PDF/HTML Template

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I am trying to add a custom record type sublist on a Bill of Materials Advanced PDF template.

I copied the code format for item table and change it with the id of the custom record type. I was able to save the PDF template without error. However, only the standard Items sublist are showing, and my custom record sublist is not showing on the printed PDF.

Here are the ids of the custom record type and its fields applied to the work order transaction.

I have also set the custom record type to be a child record of the work order parent transaction.

Custom Record Type: Solvent Add Back (id=customrecord_solvent_add_back)

Fields:
Solvent Add Back Parent [List/Record=Transaction, Record is Parent=YES] (custrecord_solvent_add_back_parent)

Solvent Item (custrecord_solvent_item)

Solvent Quantity (custrecord_solvent_quantity)

Unit (custrecord162)

Solvent Batch Number (custrecord_solvent_batch_number)

```
<#if record.custrecord_solvent_add_back_parent?has_content>
<table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="5" style="font-size:14px;">Solvent Item</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="3" style="font-size:14px;">Qty.</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="3" style="font-size:14px;">Unit</th>
    <th align="right" style="width: 143px;font-size: 14px;">Batch Number</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <#list record.custrecord_solvent_add_back_parent as item>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5" style="font-size:14px;">${item.custrecord_solvent_item}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="3" style="font-size:14px;">${item.custrecord_solvent_quantity}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="3" style="font-size:14px;">${item.custrecord162}</td>
    <td align="right" style="width: 143px;font-size: 14px;">${item.custrecord_solvent_batch_number}</td>
    </tr>
      </#list></table></#if>
```

I am fairly new to Advanced PDF/HTML source code editing product area with less than 2 months of experience. But has more than 4 years of NetSuite experience.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, its not possible to have child record/custom record data in Advanced PDF. Better go with a suitelet.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, this was what I found out as well. But it’s weird that it lets me save it. Anyways, I instead used custom body fields to be able to print them on the template.

Comment: Your welcome buddy! you can go the alternate way, by creating a userevent on script beforeload, which sets the sublist data to a custom richtext field and then get that field into your advanced pdf.